# MySQL table dependencies

Tags: mysql

I´m designing a MySQL database, and I have three tables: A, B and C.
Table A depicts the design of specific rooms of a house and table B references different possibilities for the design of the room (possible scenarios). Table C contains specific elements for design that can be applicable to each possibility:

Table A

| ID | Name | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| kitchen | Kitchen | Kitchen design |
| bathroom | Bathroom | Bathroom design |

Table B

| ID | Description | Reference_to_A |
| --- | --- | --- |
| kitchen_1 | wooden floor kitchen | kitchen |
| kitchen_2 | marble floor kitchen | kitchen |
| bathroom_1 | marble floor bathroom | bathroom |

Table C

| ID | Description | Reference_to_A | Reference_to_B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| floor_1 | marble floor | kitchen | kitchen_2 |
| floor_2 | Wooden floor | kitchen, bathroom | kitchen_1, bathroom_1 |

I need advice on how to build this architecture on MySQL, with the following constraints:

1. Each row of table C can only be associated to table B (by means of the Reference_to_B column) if table C.Reference_to_A = Table B.reference_to_A
2. I want to know if its possible to have several references to another table in a column, which I can guess its not. If not, I would appreciate another option that is efficient in terms of size of the database.

Answer (score 0):

You have one of your references reversed: Table B should also have a foreign key to reference the type of floor it uses.

Table B

| ID | Description | Reference_to_A | Reference_to_C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| kitchen_1 | wooden floor kitchen | kitchen | floor_1 |
| kitchen_2 | marble floor kitchen | kitchen | floor_2 |
| bathroom_1 | marble floor bathroom | bathroom | floor_2 |

Then you don't need any foreign key reference in Table C.

Table C

| ID | Description |
| --- | --- |
| floor_1 | marble floor |
| floor_2 | Wooden floor |

In this case, you don't have to try to put values in a reference column in a given row (in fact, [this is not a good idea in a relational database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad/3653574#3653574)). The multiplicity comes from the multiple rows in Table B.

Comment: Thank you very much for your insight. The thing is, in Table B there are several rows from Table C that can apply. For instance, for a specific kitchen design, there could be many elements applied. That´s why I would need several rows from table C to be associated to several rows in table B. Maybe an additional associations table would make sense?

Comment: That is not shown in your example data. It appears to me that Table B is the association table, representing a many-to-many relationship between room types (Table A) and floor types (Table C).